# Need help with the MX Zip plugin for EE 2.7+

Tags: add-on, update, mx-zip

I've been using the MX Zip plugin for a while, but one function it used was deprecated in version 2.7.

```
Call to undefined method EE_Functions::remove_double_slashes()
```

It's a free plugin (http://www.eec.ms/add-ons/mx-zip), but it looks like it has not been updated for a while. Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

This error was fixed in [version 3.0.1](https://github.com/MaxLazar/zip)

Comment: Max! Love your work! Thanks for replying. Sorry, I checked your User Guide, and it said "MX Zip 2.0.3 documentation", so I thought the project had been abandoned. I updated the plugin and now I get an error message: Error : "PCLZIP_ERR_READ_OPEN_FAIL (-2) : Unable to open archive '/archive_Jan_31_2014.zip' in wb mode" Any thoughts?

Comment: Host is using PHP 5.3.3, if that is the issue.

Comment: I will check it today

Comment: Any Progress, Max?

Comment: Sorry - I'm was not able do this before my business trip. I will back at Sunday.So monday - just need to add additional variable for temp folder. It is the reason of this issue;

Comment: Was there a way to fix this? I'm guessing it's a permissions thing but Where is the add-on trying to put the file?

Comment: it was fixed in last version